# Custom domain app requesting permission to access Google Account

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-account

I refer here to that page you are redirected after you login to GAE app with your google account, which asks your permission to access your google account.

Put this toghether with custom domain and https and you get my problem.

Sorry for the lengthiness. I searched everywhere. Didn't find anything. Not sure it is an OAuth issue (think not).

My configuration:

- developed myapp.appspot.com
- configured custom domain myapp.mydomain.com to point to myapp
- myapp is making use of GAE login service
- need for https posts from custom domain (!), solved as follows:

  - page is loaded in HTTP from http://myapp.mydomain.com
  - some submit HTTPS URLs are hardcoded in the page, as https://myapp.appspot.com/someservice
  - same domain policy resolved server side by means of http headers
- GAE login service applies both to *http://myapp.mydomain.com* handler AND *https://myapp.appspot.com/someservice* handler

The workflow is:

1. user not yet authenticated
2. user browse *http://myapp.mydomain.com* (not ssl)
3. user is redirected to google account login page
4. user logins
5. user is redirected to the abovementioned page: myapp is requesting permission to access user's google account
6. user grants his permission
7. user is in - OK
8. **Now comes the problem:**
9. user makes a submit to *https://myapp.appspot.com/someservice* (so that data is ssl transmitted), which is loginrequired decorated
10. login is ok, user is not again redirected to the login page,

    - I think this is because the google login is cross application (the same should appen if the user was already logged in into gmail, to say)
11. but now *https://myapp.appspot.com/* is **again** requesting permission to access user's google account - and this is the problem

The user is prompted **TWICE** to grant permission to myapp to access his account:

- once when he browse to *http://myapp.mydomain.com*
- and another one when he submits data to *https://myapp.appspot.com/someservice*

My user doesn't like it and me too !!!

I suspect this is because the user answer (Allow or No Thanks) is saved server side with respect to the URL of the app
and not with respect to some other unique id of the app.

But I have no idea how to solve it or at least work it around.

Thank you for your patience in reading up to here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What SDK/language and framework do you using?

Answer (score 0):

The cookie that is issued for the user's session is per-domain and per-protocol. As a result, the same session won't work on the appspot app and on your custom domain. This isn't an App Engine limitation - it's simply how HTTP works.

The best solution, currently, is to put the form itself on HTTPS as well (which is in general a good idea anyway).

Comment: Surely I'd like to put the form itself on HTTPS.
But to do that I need App Engine to support SSL for custom domains ...
Any news about that?

Comment: Edit: It is not a matter of cookies. Cookies are used to persist login informations, and these are cross domain. On the contrary the user permission to access google account, is saved server side (somewhere on google servers I mean), as it can be verified: 1 if you delete cookies your "allow for 30 days" answer continues to be valid; 2 if you answer "allow for 30 days" from chrome, the answer is still valid from within firefox! So stated that this information ("Allow for 30 days") **is stored server side**, it is not a matter of cookies, but it turns out to be an App Engine limitation ...